# Using link_to with post.title in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code:

```
  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <h2>Title: <%= post.title %></h2>
    <p>Author: <%= post.user.username %></p>
    <p>Created At: <%= post.created_at %></p>
    <p>Content: <%= post.content %></p>
    <p>Votes: <%= post.total_votes %></p>
    <p>Comments: <%= post.comments_count %></p>
    <ul>
      <li><%= link_to 'Show', post %></li>
      <li><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></li>
      <li><%= link_to 'Destroy', post, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %></li>
    </ul>
```

I would like to have something like this:

```
<h2><%= link_to "post.title" %></h2>
```

What's the right way of doing this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`<h2><%= link_to post.title, post %></h2>`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add text with the var you can do `<h2><%= link_to "Title : #{post.title}", post %></h2>` too.